# Insert a given value v after the 1-st, 2-nd, 4-th, 8-th ... element of a list. (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to solve this problem in SWI Prolog, and my code currently looks like this:

```
insert(L1,X,L2):-
    COUNTER = 1,
    NEXT    = 1,
    insert_plus(L1,COUNTER,NEXT,X,L2).

insert_plus([],_,_,_,[]).
insert_plus([H|T],COUNTER,NEXT,X,[H|T1]) :-    % don't insert
    COUNTER \= NEXT,
    insert_plus(T,COUNTER+1,NEXT,X,T1).
insert_plus([H|T],COUNTER,NEXT,X,[H|[X|T]]) :- % DO insert
    COUNTER = NEXT, 
    insert_plus(T,COUNTER+1,NEXT*2,X,T).
```

Can someone explain why this does not always work as expected?

```
?- insert([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],9,X).
X = [1,9,2,3,4,5,6,7].            % BAD! expected: `X = [1,9,2,9,3,4,9,5,6,7]`
```

Answer (score 1):

Prolog doesn't evaluate expressions, it proves relations. So arithmetic must be carried away explicitly. Here

```
...
insert_plus(T, COUNTER+1, NEXT, X, T1).
```

you need

```
...
SUCC is COUNTER+1,
insert_plus(T, SUCC, NEXT, X, T1).
```

the same problem - with both COUNTER and NEXT - occurs in the last rule.

Answer (score 1):

The *absolute* bare minimum that you need to change is:

```
insert_plus([],_,_,_,[]).
insert_plus([H|T],COUNTER,NEXT,X,[H|T1]) :-
    COUNTER =\= NEXT,                             % `(=\=)/2` arithmetic not-equal
    insert_plus(T,COUNTER+1,NEXT,X,T1).
insert_plus([H|T],COUNTER,NEXT,X,[H|[X|T1]]) :-   % use `T1`, not `T`
    COUNTER =:= NEXT,                             % `(=:=)/2` arithmetic equal
    insert_plus(T,COUNTER+1,NEXT*2,X,T1).         % use `T1` (as above)
```

Sample query:

```
?- insert([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],9,X).
X = [1,9,2,9,3,4,9,5,6,7].                        % expected result
```

In addition to the above changes I recommend you take advise that @CapelliC gave
[in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567756/4609915) concerning arithmetic expression evaluation using the builtin Prolog predicate `(is)/2`...

... or, even better, **use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**